# Algorithm for ASTC software texture compression/decompression

Tags: c, algorithm, opengl, graphics

Today OpenGL 4.3 and OpenGL ES 3.0 specifications [have been unveiled](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE1NTA) and for texture compression they are gonna use the newly developed [ASTC texture compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Scalable_Texture_Compression) algorithm. I am interested if there exist any purely software implementations (best in C/C++) of the algorithm. There are some code snippets [in here](http://diglib.eg.org/EG/DL/WS/EGGH/HPG12/105-114.pdf.abstract.pdf;internal&action=action.digitallibrary.ShowPaperAbstract), but they cover only the random hash used at the core of the algorithm, the full article is not disclosed. I am basing one of my projects on the [Squish](http://code.google.com/p/libsquish/) project (DXT1 in software) and would be interested how much it would benefit from ASTC. Thanks in advance if you have any resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a codec for ASTC at this [website](http://www.malideveloper.com/developer-resources/tools/astc-compressor.php) (malideveloper.com).

Source code seem to be included as well.

Hope that helps.